# Jmeter - Retrieve all embedded resources made CPU busy

Tags: jmeter

I am doing Web load testing by using Jmeter. Maximum 100 users simulate load on the server. Load is not distributed. Recently i chose download embedded resources and parallel numbers to 6 and a cache manager added to clear the cache at each iteration.

When user cross 20, CPU usage reach 95% and Jmeter gets hanged. Memory is below 60%. I have increased the heap memory to 2GB and deselected Clear cache each iteration but still CPU gets down. Non GUI also not working.

Are there any ways available to solve this issue except distributed load?

Comment: What is your machine configuration ? What jmeter version are you using ?

Comment: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz, RAM 6 GB, JMeter 3

Comment: How many vCPU/Cores  ? What JMeter version ?

Comment: 1 CPU, Jmeter 3. Its scheduled on SIT to make sure SLAs are on track before the actual test on perf environment.

Comment: Clearly 1 CPU is not enough for any test having parallel executions. You mention in your question that your cross 20 users/threads so you can get up to 6x20 threads. On 1 CPU it cannot work correctly. JMeter 3.3 will improve but 1 CPU is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue fixed in 3.2 regarding this feature:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59885

But you should always be using last JMeter version, 3.3 at time of this answer.

What is your current version ?

See this User Mailing List discussion where upgrading fixed this problem:

- http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jmeter-user/201710.mbox/%3CCAFBmedERDCTTRBL%3D0MvM4jZMMpR-LxDRRWJG2sPu%2Bs7kCF-zcQ%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: Thank you, I use Jmeter version 3. Let me try the latest.